# How can I convert an NSString to a CString in c++ without Obj-C code?

Tags: c++, macos

I am trying to get the current user name in c++ using the `NSFullUserName` function but it returns an `NSString`. Therefore, how can I convert an `NSString` to a `CString` in c++ without Obj-C code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSString` is toll-free bridged with [`CFString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html) (ie, you can just cast the pointer — the thing it points to can be interpreted as either type), and you can manipulate `CFString` using vanilla C calls.

So you'd typically attempt [`CFStringGetCStringPtr`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetCStringPtr) to try to get a pointer directly to the `NSString` contents as a C string without any copying, then fall back on allocating a suitably sized C-style array and [`CFStringGetCString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetCString) if the direct pointer isn't available (typically because the encoding you want doesn't match the `NSString`'s internal encoding).

[`CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding) will return the maximum size of buffer you need to allocate for a given encoding and string length, [`CFStringGetLength`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetLength) the length of a given string.

So e.g.

```
void Class::DoSomethingWithObjCString(NSString *objcString)
{
    CFStringRef string = (CFStringRef)objcString;

    const char *bytes = CFStringGetCStringPtr(string, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    if(bytes)
        DoSomethingWithUTF8String(bytes);
    else
    {
        size_t sizeToAllocate = 
                CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding(
                     CFStringGetLength(string), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

        char *allocatedBytes = new char[sizeToAllocate];

        CFStringGetCString(string, 
                           allocatedBytes, 
                           sizeToAllocate, 
                           kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
        DoSomethingWithUTF8String(allocatedBytes);

        delete[] allocatedBytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: what header do I need to include to access these functions?

Comment: Looks like CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h

Answer (score 2):

It is sheer silliness not to use Objective-C for this.

That said, you can cast an `NSString *` to a `CFStringRef` and use the `CFString` functions to get a C string.  You will probably find the `CFStringGetLength` and `CFStringGetCString` functions and the `kCFStringEncodingUTF8` constant useful.  Keep in mind that many Unicode characters require more than one byte to represent in UTF-8.